# hold down button to delete

Tags: iphone, ttlauncherview

Well, I cannot seem to find this anywhere on the site. So here is my question.

I have a test app which creates multiple buttons and gives each one a unique name via "+" in the toolbar. So far so good.

I am trying to find a way to press down on a button to get that Apple Jiggly effect and then delete that button and all subViews and data related to it.

Can anyone Please show me the way here?

Thanks,

Will...

Answer (score 0):

Look at three20's TTLauncherView for an example of how this is done.

API: http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_launcher_view.html

Code: http://github.com/facebook/three20 (specifically, the TTCatalog which has the TTLauncher in it)

You would have to implement deleting the subviews and data yourself after they hit the delete X box.